# Asymptotic Complexity of assigning / accessing array values in bash?

Tags: arrays, bash, performance

As it seems, to define an array value at index position `i`, it is enough to do

```
my_array[i]=whatever
```

and to later on access it,

```
v=${my_array[i]}
```

Am I correct in assuming that internally these "arrays" are nothing more than associative arrays -- hashsets? Can I count on the fact that the two referred operations will take on average `~O(1)` to run?

Thanks

Comment: If you're writing an application where you need to worry about something like this, why are you using `bash` as the implementation language?

Comment: I made a question. Can you answer it? I'm tired of all this environment in SO where no one can ask a performance related question without getting the the typical smartass reply that in no way answers what was asked. Notice that your argument can apply to any language people use nowadays such as Java or even C++. If you're worried about performance, just use assembly !!!!

Comment: No, I can't answer it without reading the bash source code. Intuitively I expect that it's a simple hash lookup, just like in most other languages with associative arrays.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. I also don't know it. That's why I started this thread, so that anyone that actually knows it shares his knowledge with us :)

Comment: @devouredelysium I think the point Barmar is trying to make is that knowledge wouldn't be more than a novelty since there is a huge performance hit with [tag:bash]. So in cases where this would be relevant [tag:bash] wouldn't.

Comment: I wouldn't have guessed it.